# calculate the degree of separation between two nodes in a connected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search

I am working on a graph library that requires to determine whether two nodes are connected or not and if connected what is the degree of separation between them
i.e number of nodes needed to travel to reach the target node from the source node.

Since its an non-weighted graph, a bfs gives the shortest path. But how to keep the track of number of nodes discovered before reaching the target node.

A simple counter which increments on discovering a new node will give a wrong answer as it may include nodes which are not even in the path.

Another way would be to treat this as a weighted graph of uniform weighted edges and using Djkastra's shortest path algorithm.

But I want to manage it with bfs only.

How to do it ?

Comment: Not sure enough to post this as an answer, but in a BFS aren't you taking an iterative approach where each iteration is a set number of links away from the starting node?  Couldn't you use *that* counter as your distance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the BFS, have each node store a pointer to its predecessor node (the node in the graph along whose edge the node was first discovered).  Then, once you've run BFS, you can repeatedly follow this pointer from the destination node to the source node.  If you count up how many steps this takes, you will have the distance from the destination to the source node.

Alternatively, if you need to repeatedly determine the distances between nodes, you might want to use the Floyd-Warshall all-pairs shortest paths algorithm, which if precomputed would let you immediately read off the distances between any pair of nodes.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why a simple counter wouldn't work.  In this case, breadth-first search would definitely give you the shortest path.  So what you want to do is attach a property to every node called 'count'. Now when you encounter a node that you have not visited yet, you populate the 'count' property with whatever the current count is and move on.

If later on, you come back to the node, you should know by the populated count property that it has already been visited.

***EDIT***: To expand a bit on my answer here, you'll have to maintain a variable that'll track the degree of separation from your starting node as you navigate the graph. For every new set of children that you load into the queue, make sure that you increment the value in that variable.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to know is the distance (possibly to cut off the search if the distance is too large), and all edges have the same weight (i.e. 1):

Pseudocode:

```
Let Token := a new node object which is different from every node in the graph.
Let Distance := 0
Let Queue := an empty queue of nodes
Push Start node and Token onto Queue 

(Breadth-first-search):
While Queue is not empty:
    If the head of Queue is Target node:
        return Distance
    If the head of Queue is Token:
        Increment Distance
        Push Token onto back of the Queue
    If the head of Queue has not yet been seen:
        Mark the head of the Queue as seen
        Push all neighbours of the head of the Queue onto the back of Queue
    Pop the head of Queue
(Did not find target)
```